# How to echo an error message in the place that I want

Tags: php, html

I have a if else statement below where it will look through the database and display error if the email isn't in the database. I wanna echo the error message beside my submit button. Currently my error message will always appear at the top of the page.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($search_user_email) > 0) {
    echo "<p style=\"color:red\"><b>Email found!</b></p>";
}
else {
echo "<p style=\"color:red\"><b>Email not found!</b></p>";
}


<tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 18px">
<td>
<span style="font-size:10pt;">Search by email:</span>
</td>
<td>
<form action="" method="post" name="search_email_form">
<input type="text" style="height:15px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_input"></input>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" style="height:22px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_submit" value="Search"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: This is so basic I have to wonder if you stopped to actually think about it.

Answer (score 4):

Just save the error message into a variable and display it as needed:

```
$errMsg="";
if (mysql_num_rows($search_user_email) > 0) {
    $errMsg= "<p style=\"color:red\"><b>Email found!</b></p>";
}
else {
$errMsg= "<p style=\"color:red\"><b>Email not found!</b></p>";
}


<tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 18px">
<td>
<span style="font-size:10pt;">Search by email:</span>
</td>
<td>
<form action="" method="post" name="search_email_form">
<input type="text" style="height:15px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_input"></input>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" style="height:22px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_submit" value="Search"></input>
</form><?php echo $errMsg; ?>
```

Comment: I think you should do `if (isset($errMsg))`

Comment: @blo I actually looked at my code again, and saved the input from both a success and fail on the query, so it will be better to display it in either case.

Comment: Yeah, now it's not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

set a flag if there is an error

```
if (mysql_num_rows($search_user_email) > 0) {
    $emailError = true;
}
else {
echo "<p style=\"color:red\"><b>Email not found!</b></p>";
}


<tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 18px">
<td>
<span style="font-size:10pt;">Search by email:</span>
</td>
<td>
<form action="" method="post" name="search_email_form">
<input type="text" style="height:15px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_input"></input>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" style="height:22px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_submit" value="Search"></input>
<?php if($emailError)
    echo "<p style=\"color:red\"><b>Email found!</b></p>";
    $emailError = false;
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($search_user_email) > 0) {
    $message = '<p style="color:red"><b>Email found!</b></p>';
} else {
    $message = '<p style="color:red"><b>Email not found!</b></p>';
}
?>

<tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 18px">
<td>
<span style="font-size:10pt;">Search by email:</span>
</td>
<td>
<form action="" method="post" name="search_email_form">
<input type="text" style="height:15px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_input" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" style="height:22px; font-size:10pt;" name="search_email_submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($message)) {
    echo $message;
}
?>
```

*By the way, PHP is no longer supporting the **mysql_*** functions and they will be deleted sooner or later.*

**EDIT:**
You don't need to put `</input>`, you can just do this:

```
<input ... />
```